# Creating a swipe-able app intro screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm trying to replicate the effect done in [this gif](https://d262ilb51hltx0.cloudfront.net/max/800/1%2atKuXa5qf4aSwuSnv05uqxQ.gif).

I'm thinking this would be done with UIPanGestureRecognizer, but I'm not sure. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try (or search for a 3rd party implementation on cocoacontrols.com)

Comment: @Wain I've looked and can't find anything, do you know of any?

Comment: it is swipe left not pan. it can be done (crudely) by adding the UIGesture to the view and then on swipe left method reveal a new view.

Comment: I've tried doing this with a `UIPanGesture` but can't figure out exactly how to do it

Comment: @XCodeMonkey, pan gesture is better for the request. One example for guidance https://github.com/ECSlidingViewController/ECSlidingViewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished quite easily with UIPanGestureRecognizer. Use translationInView to find out how much the user's finger moved by, and move your view according to the finger movement. In this example, self refers to the view controller, view1 is the view on top you want to drag.

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer* pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:pan];
```

And handle it:

```
-(void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender
{
    CGFloat xMovement = [sender translationInView:sender.view].x;
    // Do something with the movement
    view1.frame = CGRectOffset(view1.frame, xMovement, 0);

    // Then reset the translation
    [sender setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:sender.view];
}
```

Comment: How would I get rid of the view I'm dismissing by swiping?

Comment: When the view is finally off screen you can set the `hidden` property to true, or remove it from it's superview